# jQuery - get .css() value and append to a input value

Tags: jquery

I want get the following element style and append them to input value.

***append CSS property value to input `value`, where property is equal to input `name`.***

**Here is my div from where I want to get style**

```
<div class="styler">
   <h3 style="color:#555;font-size:30px;font-family:'open sans';">
        I am Heading
   </h3>
</div>
```

**And this is the input where I want to append my styles**

```
<div class="myStyle">
   <input name="color" />
   <input name="font-size" />
   <input name="font-family" />
</div>
```

Comment: $(documnet).ready(function(){ $(input[name]).attr('style', $('.styler h3').attr('style')) });. Is this you are looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
var h3 = $(".styler h3");
$('.myStyle input').each(function(){
    this.value = h3.css(this.name);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/8r4dM/)

Comment: Thank you for answering. I love your solutions, small and effective

Answer (score 0):

You may try this too

```
$('.myStyle input').val(function(i){ 
    return $('.styler h3').attr('style').split(';')[i].split(':')[1]; 
});
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/SN4e4/1/)